# INRIA SPOON API MethodCalls-Retrieve Callee Classes for method.getExecutable() and method.getTarget()

Tags: java, methods, inria-spoon

I am trying to extract method calls for a project that I am parsing using the tool spoon developed by INRIA, I already have a methods mysql table where I stored all the methods (methodid, methodname, classid, classname ). I am using the following code to extract the methodcalls within my project:

```
    SpoonAPI spoon = new Launcher();
    spoon.addInputResource("C:\\Users\\mouna\\Downloads\\chess and gantt code\\workspace_codeBase\\Chess\\src");
    spoon.getEnvironment().setAutoImports(true);
    spoon.getEnvironment().setNoClasspath(true);
    CtModel model = spoon.buildModel();
    //List<String> classnames= new ArrayList<String>(); 

    // Interact with model
    Factory factory = spoon.getFactory();
    ClassFactory classFactory = factory.Class();
    MethodFactory methodFactory = factory.Method(); 
List<methodcalls> methodcallsList = new ArrayList<methodcalls>(); 
    for(CtType<?> clazz : classFactory.getAll()) {

    for(CtMethod<?> method :clazz.getMethods()) {

        String methname=method.getSimpleName(); 
        System.out.println("CALLER METHOD=====>"+methname);
         List<CtInvocation> methodcalls = method.getElements(new TypeFilter<>(CtInvocation.class)); 
        for( CtInvocation calledmethod: methodcalls) {

            //CALLEE EXECUTABLE 
            String CALLEENAME= calledmethod.getExecutable().getSignature().toString(); 
            String methodCallee=calledmethod.getExecutable().toString();
            if(calledmethod.getTarget()!=null) {
        //CALLEE TARGET  
                String CALLEENAMETARGET= calledmethod.getTarget().toString(); 
                System.out.println("TARGET: "+ CALLEENAMETARGET);
            }
        //CALLEE METHOD INFORMATION  
            ResultSet callingmethodsrefined2 = st.executeQuery("SELECT methods.* from methods where methods.methodname='"+CALLEENAME+"' "); 
            while(callingmethodsrefined2.next()) {
                String CALLEECLASSNAME = callingmethodsrefined2.getString("classname"); 
                String CALLEECLASSID = callingmethodsrefined2.getString("classid"); 
                String CALLEEID = callingmethodsrefined2.getString("id"); 
                System.out.println("CALLEE CLASS NAME: "+ CALLEECLASSNAME);
            }



            //CALLER METHOD INFORMATION     
            String CALLERCLASSNAME=clazz.getQualifiedName() ; 
            String CallerMethod= method.getSignature(); 
            ResultSet callingmethodsrefined = st.executeQuery("SELECT methods.* from methods where methods.methodname='"+CallerMethod+"'and methods.classname='"+CALLERCLASSNAME+"'"); 
            if(callingmethodsrefined.next()) {
                String CallerMethodID = callingmethodsrefined.getString("id"); 
                String CALLERCLASSNAME = callingmethodsrefined.getString("classname"); 
                String CALLERCLASSID = callingmethodsrefined.getString("classid"); 
                System.out.println("CALLEE METHOD ID: "+ CALLEEID);
            }




            String fullcaller= CALLERCLASSNAME+"."+CallerMethod; 
            String fullcallee= CALLEECLASSNAME+"."+CALLEENAME; 
            methodcalls methodcall= new methodcalls(CALLEEID, fullcaller, CALLEECLASSNAME, CallerMethodID, fullcallee, CALLERCLASSNAME); 

            if( methodcall.contains(methodcallsList, methodcall)==false && CallerMethodID!=null && CALLEEID!=null) {
                String statement = "INSERT INTO `methodcalls`(`callermethodid`,  `callername`,  `callerclass`, `callerclassid`,`fullcaller`,`calleemethodid`,  `calleename`, `calleeclass`,  `calleeclassid`,  `fullcallee`) VALUES ('"+CallerMethodID +"','" +CallerMethod+"','" +CALLERCLASSNAME+"','" +CALLERCLASSID+"','" +fullcaller+"','" +CALLEEID+"','" +CALLEENAME+"','" +CALLEECLASSNAME+"','" +CALLEECLASSID+"','" +fullcallee+"')";

                st.executeUpdate(statement);
                methodcallsList.add(methodcall); 
            }


        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to retrieve the class to which the callee belongs, I am only able to retrieve the method signature, this is a problem since the same method like for example isWhite() can be found in multiple classes so I will end up with multiple results when I query my database "methods" table only based on the method name. I have tried using this to retrieve the class to which the callee belongs to String methodCallee=calledmethod.getExecutable().getClass().getSimpleName(); but that returned: "CtExecutableReferenceImpl".

Another problem that I have is that I am relying on calledmethod.getExecutable() to extract the method callees. However, calledmethod.getTarget() can contain in itself some callees, I printed the content of calledmethod.getTarget() and I got TARGET: getLastPly().getDestination() for one of the callers. In case the target is made of a succession of callees, is there a way to separate all of them? Also, I need to know the list of classes that each of these "target callees" belongs to, I am pretty new to Spoon so I don't really know which APIs to use

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using this to retrieve the class to which the callee belongs to String methodCallee=calledmethod.getExecutable().getClass().getSimpleName(); but that returned: "CtExecutableReferenceImpl".

I think the method you are looking for is actually `getDeclaringType()`. This method is not available from the `CtExecutable` interface so you have to check that your executable is indeed an instance of `CtMethod` and after casting it you can use `getDeclaringType`.
See: http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/mvnsites/spoon-core/apidocs/spoon/reflect/declaration/CtTypeMember.html#getDeclaringType--

I'm not sure to understand your second problem: could you provide an example it would be helpful there.